# Error connecting server and client programs

Tags: tcpclient, tcp, tcpserver

I wrote those two codes. server and client.

```
//***Server***


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define OPSZ 4
void ErrorHandling(char *message);
int calculate(int opnum, int opnds[], char op);

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET hServSock, hClntSock;
    char opinfo[BUF_SIZE];
    int result, opndCnt, i;
    int recvCnt, recvLen;
    SOCKADDR_IN servAdr, clntAdr;
    int clntAdrSize;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage : %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
        ErrorHandling("WSAStartup() error!");

    hServSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(hServSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        ErrorHandling("socket() error");

    memset(&servAdr, 0, sizeof(servAdr));
    servAdr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAdr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAdr.sin_port = htons(atoi((char*)argv[1]));

    if(bind(hServSock, (SOCKADDR*)&servAdr, sizeof(servAdr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        ErrorHandling("bind() error");
    if(listen(hServSock, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        ErrorHandling("listen() error");
    clntAdrSize = sizeof(clntAdr);

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)  
    {
        opndCnt = 0;
        hClntSock = accept(hServSock, (SOCKADDR*)&clntAdr, &clntAdrSize);
        recv(hClntSock, (char*)&opndCnt, 1, 0);

        recvLen = 0;

        while((opndCnt*OPSZ+1) > recvLen)   
        {
            recvCnt = recv(hClntSock, &opinfo[recvLen], BUF_SIZE-1, 0);
            recvLen += recvCnt;
        }
        result = calculate(opndCnt, (int*)opinfo, opinfo[recvLen-1]);   
        send(hClntSock, (char*)&result, sizeof(result), 0); 
        closesocket(hClntSock);
    }
    closesocket(hServSock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

int calculate(int opnum, int opnds[], char op)
{
    int result = opnds[0], i;

    switch(op)
    {
    case '+':
        for(i=1; i<opnum; i++) result += opnds[i];
        break;
    case '-':
        for(i=1; i<opnum; i++) result -= opnds[i];
        break;
    case '*':
        for(i=1; i<opnum; i++) result *= opnds[i];
        break;
    }

    return result;
}

void ErrorHandling(char *message)
{
    fputs(message, stderr);
    fputc('\n', stderr);
    exit(1);
}






//***client***


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define RLT_SIZE 4  
#define OPSZ 4
void ErrorHandling(char *message);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET hSocket;
    char opmsg[BUF_SIZE];
    int result, opndCnt, i;
    SOCKADDR_IN servAdr;

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage : %s <IP> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
        ErrorHandling("WSAStartup() error!");

    hSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(hSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        ErrorHandling("socket() error");

    memset(&servAdr, 0, sizeof(servAdr));
    servAdr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAdr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    servAdr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

    if(connect(hSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&servAdr, sizeof(servAdr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        ErrorHandling("connect() error!");
    else
        puts("Connected..........");

    fputs("Operand count: ", stdout);
    scanf("%d", &opndCnt);
    opmsg[0] = (char)opndCnt;

    for(i=0; i<opndCnt; i++)
    {
        printf("Operand %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", (int*)&opmsg[i*OPSZ+1]);
    }
    fgetc(stdin);
    fputs("Operator: ", stdout);
    scanf("%c", &opmsg[opndCnt*OPSZ+1]);
    send(hSocket, opmsg, opndCnt*OPSZ+2, 0);
    recv(hSocket, (char*)&result, RLT_SIZE, 0);


    printf("Operation result: %d \n", result);
    closesocket(hSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

void ErrorHandling(char *message)
{
    fputs(message, stderr);
    fputc('\n', stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

I compiled those two codes (that means 2 projects separately) and that made Debug folder.

I saved those 2 project folders to Desktop.

I started cmd and then wrote

> cd Desktop-> cd server -> cd Debug -> server 9190

but the error happens (I first coded server to turn the server on, and then I was planning to make the connection between the server and client.)

[image]

Comment: This question might be off-topic for Stack Overflow since it involves a simple typographical error and thus might not be useful to future readers. You can avoid this in future by creating a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

`int main(int argc, char *argv)` should read `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

`char *argv[]` would also work.

[What does int argc, char *argv[] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean) might be worth a read.

[Here is a link to a tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/) that will help you get started with winsock programming.